# Работа с Session в AspNet Core MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Делал корзину для сайта по одному примеру. Создание сессии выглядит так.

```
public Cart GetCart()
        {
            Cart cart = (Cart)Session["Cart"];
            if (cart == null)
            {
                cart = new Cart();
                Session["Cart"] = cart;
            }
            return cart;
        }
```

У меня естественно не сработало и я заменил Session на HttpContext.Session и все равное не работает.
Как можно это исправить?

Comment: почитайте тут: https://metanit.com/sharp/aspnet5/2.26.php

Comment: [Session and state management in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/app-state?view=aspnetcore-6.0)

Comment: _не работает_ - нет такого понятия в программировании. Есть конкретное поведение и чёткое описание проблемы. Код не компилируется? Компилируется, но не запускается? Запускается, но падает с исключением? С каким исключением? Работает, но выдаёт неправильный результат? Какой результат выдаёт? А какой должен быть?

Answer (score 0):

1. Для работы с сессиями, нужно явно подключать специальные сервисы для этого в ASP.NET Core. Возможно вы уже это сделали, но я все же повторю этот код.
   Для .NET 6 и выше, это нужно сделать в файле Program.cs.

builder. Services.AddHttpContextAccessor( );

```
builder.Services.AddSession()  //Здесь нужно добавить настройки для сессий.
```

Далее в конвейере добавляем компонент

```
app.UseSession();
```

2. Однако в объекте Session, могут храниться только целые числа или строки, и для сохранении данных о товарах включенных в корзину покупок нужно будет создать расширение для методов Get и Set для Session, в которых нужно будет настроить сериализацию или десериализацию сложных объектов хранящихся в сессии, в нашем случае это строка с данными о Товаре из Корзины покупок. Так вот данные нужно передавать в виде строк или получать строки и преобразовывать в данные о Товаре. Именно такая настройка хранения данных о Товарах в Сессиях используется в курсе об интернет-магазине на ASP.NET Core MVC, вот [видео](https://youtu.be/RGqg8ltFSUw) из этого курса.